# Openlaszlo embed.js issue

Tags: migration, openlaszlo, lzx

I have a application where ctrl + s key combination is handled. So when i press this key a new screen appears with some details. This is working fine in mozilla FF 15.0 and 16.0 but when i am viewing it in an AIR web browser runtime 3.4 in full screen mode, the browser is getting minimized and the screen is also not appearing properly.

And later i discovered that when i was using the embed.js file of OL 3.3 version i am not facing this issue the air browser is working fine. But when i am using the latest embed-compressed.js i am getting this. Any idea why this is happening ?

I am using Openlaszlo 5.0.x  this issue is also happening in OL 4.9's script

Comment: On which operating system are you? ctrl + s is normally mapped to the "save" functionality, is there any mapping for that key predefined in Adobe AIR? Did you try using a different key combination to see if that works?

Comment: @Stevie: I am using windows xp. The other combinations (ctrl +k, ctrl + j)that is present in the application is working fine. But Ctrl +s alone is giving the problem.  No I didn't specify any mappings. The AIR browser is working fine with the old embed.js.

Comment: Could you add the information if it is a DHTML application or SWF application? If it is an SWF application, have you considered deploying it as an AIR SWF app vs. an AIR HTML app?

Comment: @RajuBitter: It's a swf APP. But it's not an AIR swf app. The AIR application has a html tag which loads the swf app.